# Can we download the jenkins Git plugin from centos terminal?

Tags: git, jenkins, centos, jenkins-plugins

My jenkins is installed on centos. I am accessing the jenkins homepage from windows where,i don't have to access to internet. am i able to download the jenkins plugin from the centos terminal.

Comment: I'm puzzled, why don't you just install the plugin using the update Center UI? If you are behind a proxy, you'll need to update the advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can download the required jenkins plugin in centos from [Here](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/).

Save the downloaded *.hpi/*.jpi file into the $JENKINS_HOME/plugins directory and restart Jenkins.

Comment: I did it just downloaded the .hpi files and copied into jenkins home.
But that was not working ,also tried to reload from jenkins homepage no change and Thank you for answer.
I found another way we can upload the hpi files in manage jenkins->manage plugins->advanced ->upload files ->restart jenkins it's working.